# Connect to postfix from two different servers with two different user/pass combinations

Tags: server, 18.04, email, postfix, smtp

I have 3 vps servers: two of them hosting a website each and a third one hosts postfix.

```
VPS [1]: domainone.com
VPS [2]: domaintwo.com
VPS [3]: smtp.domainthree.com
```

How do i connect from vps [1] to smtp(vps [3]) with a user/pass combination and  from vps[2] to smtp with another user/pass combination?

Answer (score 0):

On `smtp.domainthree.com`:

1. you set up authenticated SMTP sessions for posfix
2. you add (with `adduser`) two users
3. you set their passwords (with `passwd`)

On each of your VPS servers:

4. you configure authenticated mail submissions, each server using a different user

You'll need to lookup how to do 1. Also you'll need to lookup how to do 4.

I'm using `msmtp` for 4. and it's fairly easy to configure. You should find docu on how to do that under `/usr/share/doc/msmtp` and `man mstmp` and `/etc/msmtprc`.

Also, you'll probably find more topic expertise on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).